# http server and client implementing head and get method

Tags: java, http, get, httpclient, head

I'm trying to make a simple http client server using java. It will show the client's request as well as the server's response. For example server will send back

```
   HTTP/1.0 200 OK
   Connection: Close. etc.
```

Previously i had a echo client server. Now I've turned my echo server to act as a http server. I've tried Goggling about how to implement the head and get with the client but i noticed usually all of the example used apache framework. Is there a way to implement these method without apache framework.
My echo client which i'm trying to convert into a http client:

```
       import java.io.*;
       import java.net.*;

          public class Ec1
      {
      public static void main(String[] args)
        {
           try
        {
          Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 80);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new                                 InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
           BufferedReader con = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
          String line;
           do
        {
         line = r.readLine();
          if ( line != null )
        System.out.println(line);
       line = con.readLine();
          w.println(line);
        }
         while ( !line.trim().equals("bye") );
          }
          catch (Exception err)
        {
         System.err.println(err);
        }
        }
     }
```

My Http server:

```
          import java.io.BufferedReader;
          import java.io.InputStreamReader;
          import java.io.PrintWriter;
          import java.net.ServerSocket;
          import java.net.Socket;

          public class Echo
                 { 

 protected void start() {
        ServerSocket s;

        System.out.println("Webserver starting up on port 80");

        try {
          // create the main server socket
          s = new ServerSocket(80);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Error: " + e);
          return;
        }
        Socket clientSocket = null; 
        System.out.println ("Waiting for connection.....");
        try { 
             clientSocket = s.accept(); 
             System.out.println("Connection, sending data.");
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                     clientSocket.getInputStream()));
             PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());


             String str = ".";
             while (!str.equals(""))
               str = in.readLine();


             out.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
             out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
             out.println("Server: Bot");

             out.println("");

             out.println("<H1>Welcome to the Ultra Mini-WebServer</H2>");
             out.flush();
             clientSocket.close();
             s.close(); 
           } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Error: " + e);
           }
         }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            WebServer ws = new WebServer();
            ws.start();
                    }
           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is, just interpret your request you're getting from the client.

From the following code (in `HttpServer`), parse:

```
String str = ".";
while (!str.equals("")) {
  str = in.readLine();

  if (str.startsWith("HEAD")) {
      //Head execution here...
  }
}
```

Etc...

Answer (score 1):

Everybody uses some kind of library or framework for the client and/or the server side because HTTP is somewhat complex and there is no need to reinvent every wheel. However, it is quite possible to write your own implementation by starting directly from the RFCs for HTTP.